# How to synchronise application state with router state in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-router-store

Is there a best practice approach in Angular2+ for making the URL the single source of truth for application state.

EmberJs has Route Models, each segment of the URL can have a model and the model for each URL segment is resolved from left to right, so nested pages can use the model from parent pages because the nested page model is resolved after the parents.

I'd like to achieve something similar in Angular2 if it is a common or recommended approach.

Comment: I've re-posted this question on Software Engineering, it's probably too vague for SO. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370619/how-to-synchronise-application-state-with-router-state-in-angular-2